# Python - AttributeError: __getitem__

Tags: python, image-processing, numpy

I am required to access all images in a folder and store it in a matrix using python. Here is my code.

```
import Image
import os
from PIL import Image
from numpy import *
import numpy as np


#import images
dirname = "C:\\Users\\Karim\\Downloads\\att_faces\\New folder"

#get number of images and dimentions
path, dirs, files = os.walk(dirname).next()
num_images = len(files)
image_file = "C:\\Users\\Karim\\Downloads\\att_faces\\New folder\\2.pgm"
im = Image.open(image_file)
width, height = im.size



images = []

for x in xrange(1, num_images):
    filename = os.listdir(dirname)[x]
    filepath = os.path.join(dirname, filename)
    img = Image.open(filepath)
    img = im.convert('L')
    images[:, x] = img[:]

print images
```

but I am getting the error: `AttributeError: __getitem__`

from the line: `images[:, x] = img[:]`

Comment: Because `img` is an `Image` and have not `__getitem__` implemented, so you can not write `img[something]` in your code. What do you mean from this line of code?

Comment: @MostafaR I mean that the error message looks like this:`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Karim/Desktop/Bachelor 2/New folder/new2.py", line 31, in <module>
    images[:, x] = img[:]
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 512, in __getattr__
    raise AttributeError(name)
AttributeError: __getitem__` 
I don't understand what you mean. Please explain more

Comment: I mean, it's normal to get error on `img[:]`, because it's a meaningless line of code. If you explain what do you want from this line of code, we can help you.

Comment: In my view, you should change this line of code to `images.append(img)`. But I'm not sure about this, because I don't know what you want.

Comment: @MostafaR I want to put all images in the directory into a two dimensional array, so `img` is supposed to be an array of a single image and `images` is the two dimensional array that I want as an output

Comment: `img` is not an array; it's an `Image` object. Try `images[:,x] = img` (I'm not familiar with `numpy` arrays, though) or `images[:,x] = [img]`.